# Woman follows a man with a special camera around the world

Tags: identify-this-movie

This may be a movie from the 80s or 90s.

The movie starts with the main actress driving her car, I believe somewhere in Italy, and she rides out of the city. On some mountain she crashed with some people. The car of the other people is destroyed so they asked her to take them to France. They had a lot of money with them. In France the actress meet some guy that intrigues her and she decides to follow him, I think in Berlin, and after that to Tokyo, I think. In Tokyo she found out that he records what he see with his special camera so his blind mother can see what he saw. Both of them after that go to the USA where they meet his family somewhere in desert in some kind of secret camp...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the movie "Until the End of the World", from 1991 with William Hurt, Solveig Dommartin and Max Von Sydow.

Basically, Dommartin has an accident with some bank robbers, and they enlist her to take the money to a drop in Paris. There she meets Hurt who is a fugitive being chased by the CIA for a camera his father invented that allows recording of dreams and vision. They end up in Australia at Sydow's research facility where they hope to play the images for his blind mother.

IMDB entry is [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101458/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt).